# Perform a Mann-Kendall test on grd dataset downloaded from imd portal

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, hydrology

I have a grd file downloaded from imd portal, now I want to perform a mann kendall test on this grd dataset. But I am not getting how to read grd file in Python and how to perform Mann-Kendall test, as it have different data format then normal, I wrote this code for the normal Excel sheet data values. Now how to write it for grd file:

```py
def apply_mann_kendall(data,alpha=0.05):
    n = len(data)
    x = np.arange(n)
    s = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            s += np.sign(data[j] - data[i])
    unique_vals, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
    g = len(unique_vals)

    if g == n:
        var_s = (n*(n-1)*(2*n+5))/18
    else:
        tp = np.zeros(g)
        for k in range(g):
            tp[k] = sum(counts[:k+1])
        var_s = (n*(n-1)*(2*n+5) + np.sum(tp*(tp-1)*(2*tp+5)))/18

    if s > 0:
        z = (s - 1) / np.sqrt(var_s)
    elif s < 0:
        z = (s + 1) / np.sqrt(var_s)
    else:
        z = 0

    p = 2*(1-norm.cdf(abs(z)))  # two tail test
    h = abs(z) > norm.ppf(1-alpha/2)

    if (z < 0) and h:
        trend = 'decreasing'
    elif (z > 0) and h:
        trend = 'increasing'
    else:
        trend = 'no trend'
        
    differences = np.zeros(int(n * (n - 1) / 2))
    slopes = np.zeros(int(n * (n - 1) / 2))
    beg = 0
    for kt in range(1, n):
        ned = beg + n - kt
        differences[beg:ned] = data[kt:n] - data[kt - 1]
        slopes[beg:ned] = (data[kt:n] - data[kt - 1]) / (x[kt:n] - x[kt - 1])
        beg = ned
    slope = np.median(slopes)

    return {'trend': trend, 'h': h, 'p': p, 'z': z, 'slope': slope}
```